# Ionic Capacitor Android error when using Serial plugin - Cordova_not_available when connecting to external device

Tags: android, ionic-framework, usb, capacitor

**Describe the bug**

I'm trying to run Serial lib on a ionic with capacitor. However, when executing the code, I'm obtaining the error *Native: tried calling Serial.requestPermission, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator* **cordova_not_available**.

**Code**

```
this.serial.requestPermission().then(() => {
           this.serial.open({
                     baudRate: 9800,
                     dataBits: 4,
                     stopBits: 1,
                     parity: 0,
                     dtr: true,
                     rts: true,
                     sleepOnPause: false
              }).then(() => {
            console.log('Serial connection opened');
            });
        }).catch((error: any) => console.log(error));
    }
```

**To Reproduce**

1. Version of cordovarduino / cordova

"cordovarduino": "0.0.10",
cordova - (not using, but for testing, tried to install it via npm install, but the error persisted. Keep in mind that this is not a cordova project, but a capacitor project)

2. Type of board you use and code

Real Device : Herelink RC.
Emulator: Pixel3 API 25

**Expected behavior**

Find an external device. When no USB is connected, 'USB not found' or something similar was expected.

**Additional context**

Note 1: On API 29 (Android 10) is working, but our real device (HereLink) just runs Android 7.1.2.

`ionic info`

Ionic:

Ionic CLI                     : 6.16.1 (/home/grolo/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.1/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.6.7
@angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.1102.13
@angular-devkit/schematics    : 11.2.13
@angular/cli                  : 11.2.13
@ionic/angular-toolkit        : 3.1.1

Capacitor:

Capacitor CLI      : 3.0.0
@capacitor/android : 3.0.2
@capacitor/core    : 3.0.0
@capacitor/ios     : 3.0.0

Utility:

cordova-res                          : not installed globally
native-run (update available: 1.4.0) : 1.3.0

System:

NodeJS : v14.16.1 (/home/grolo/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.1/bin/node)
npm    : 6.14.12
OS     : Linux 5.4

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator cordova_not_available.**

> By focusing this error...i  generally observe there is no error in our
> code function, methods, plugins .may be you are trying to run in your
> browser. Just connect USB and run in device. If this is not possible
> try to run in emulator create it from android studio..

like using of Location and Camera you need to run in device or simulator..

But Emulator may not get Respond as actual device do.
Hope you understand what I want to explain you